# Calling function in render not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

Unable to call a function from within render. My component is:

```
class MyComp extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getUsers();
  };

  getUsersfunction(users){
   return(
      console.log("i was called");
    users.map((user, idx) => {
      return (
        <View key={idx}>
          <Text style={styles.userNames}> ID: {user.id} - Name: {user.name} </Text>
        </View> 
       )
      });
    )
  };


  render() {
    console.log("USERS: ", this.props.users);
    const { users } = this.props.users

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <ScrollView>
            { users.length ? (
              {this.getUsersfunction(users)}   // <= Is this the correct way?
            ) : null }
         </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// mapStatetoProps and mapDispatchToProps here.   

export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps ) ( MyComp );
```

Error is `this` is a reserved word. Console.log sows all the users in an array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `getUsersfunction` isn't currently returning anything. You may want to add a return statement.

Comment: Updated question. It was my mistake here. Original code has the return. Still nothing is returned. But console logs `"i was called"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**James Emanon** is quite correct.

But If I were you I would move the logic to check if there is something to render or not into the function itself.

```js
getUsersfunction(){
  const { users } = this.props.users

  if(!users)
    return null;

    return(
      console.log("i was called");
      users.map((user, idx) => {
          return (
            <View key={idx}>
              <Text style={styles.userNames}> ID: {user.id} - Name: {user.name} </Text>
            </View> 
           )
      });
    )
};
```

And then, Render becomes much cleaner:

```js
<ScrollView>
  {this.getUsersfunction()}
</ScrollView>
```

Another refactor I would suggest is, since you already have *users* in `this.props` you don't need to pass them through params, so you can use it directly in your function.

Binding your function is also important, even when react does that four you, depending on the context where you actually are it could be lost:

```js
constructor() {
  this.getUsersFunction = this.getUsersFunction.bind(this)
}
```

By this way you will not receive errors, but if you cant render then users, you will have to start evaluating if there is really something to render.

Answer (score 3):

Or a little shorter, By adding those curly braces, you created a different return type of object instead of your wanted jsx.

```
<ScrollView>
    { users.length && this.getUsersfunction(users) }
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the curly braces:

```
{ users.length ? (
  this.getUsersfunction(users)   // Now it's correct
) : null }
```

Comment: To be clear;  Curly brackets denote when you want to insert JS into a JSX context.  But once you are already in a JS context, the curly brackets represent a JSON object.  The original code was returning a JSON object that was attempting to set a variable of name `this.getUsersfunction(users)`, which should clearly not work.

Comment: Tried that. Get no error but nothing is returned. But console logs `"i was called"`. Updated the function in question. Thanks.

Comment: You need to remove the console from return. Put the console.log statement above the return

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `bind` `getUsersFunction` method in the component's constructor:

```
constructor() {
  this.getUsersFunction = this.getUsersFunction.bind(this)
}

render() {
  const { users } = this.props.users

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        { users.length && this.getUsersfunction(users) }
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you did `const { users } = this.props.users`

but you should did `const { users } = this.props`